# Cumulative total from a table

Tags: sql, window-functions

I have a table which calculates the headcount based on the date they are hired , but i want to see a cumulative hc for tat year for example I might have hired only 20  in 2016 but i should show my overall hc till 2015+20 in 2016 and the it should go on.
if my requirement is from 2019 onwards it should show the cumulative till 2019 and go from there.

```
select FISC_YR_ID,ASSOC_TYPE_NM,
count(ASSOC_BDGE_NBR) over(order by FISC_YR_ID,FISC_MTH_ID rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as CUM_HC
 --order by FISC_YR_ID asc ) 
from HC_table
where FISC_YR_ID >2018
```

this is the table

[image]

Comment: Tag the question with the database that you use. And what is your expected output for this sample data?

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite tell what the query has to do with the question or sample data, so this focuses on the question.

You can use a cumulative sum:

```
select year, hired, sum(hired) over (order by year)
from t;
```

If you want to filter this, then use a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select year, hired, sum(hired) over (order by year) as cumulative
      from t
     ) t
where year > 2018
```